# How to flatten column of lists when some contain Null values?

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

This is likely a very obvious question, but I have a column containing lists that I am trying to flatten: i.e `[AB, CD] -> AB, CD`.

Sample dataframe:

```
data = [
    ["ABC", ["AB", "AB", "EF"]],
    ["DEF", ["CD", "EF"]],
    ["GHI", ["JK"]],
    [
        "JKL",
        np.nan,
    ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "list"])
df
```

I am applying this function to said column:

```
def func(string):
    flattened_string = ", ".join(map(str, string))
    return flattened_string
```

```
df = df["list_column"].apply(func)
```

However there are a few rows containing `NaN` values that initiate the error `"TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"`. Is there any way I can modify this function to fix this? Or perhaps (likely) a much better way to do this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If needing to preserve the `NaN` values in the column, we can use [setting with enlargement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) by only joining the [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) values in the column and assigning back:

```
df['list'] = df.loc[df['list'].notnull(), 'list'].map(','.join)
```

Or if there are non-strings in the lists:

```
df['list'] = df.loc[
    df['list'].notnull(), 'list'
].map(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

`df`:

```
    ID      list
0  ABC  AB,AB,EF
1  DEF     CD,EF
2  GHI        JK
3  JKL       NaN  # Still NaN not empty string
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to fill the `NaN`s in that column to something that's empty but iterable, like `""` or `[]`. You can also simplify your function to just `.apply(", ".join)`, assuming the column of lists you're joining are only strings.

```py
df["list"] = df["list"].fillna("").apply(", ".join)
```

Comment: One word. clever +1

Comment: wow I really overcomplicated that. thank you!!!

Comment: Finally snuck a Pandas answer in under your radar Corralien :D